# how to specify max frame rate, width and height, and quality of webrtc videos?

Tags: video, webrtc, frame-rate, simplewebrtc

I want to decrease the quality of videos in WebRTC using SimpleWebRTC, How can I do that?

I did this but doesn't work properly:

```
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
    remoteVideosEl: 'remoteVideo',
    autoRequestMedia: true,
    media: {
        video: someFunction(), // which returns true after some IFs
        audio: someFunction()  // same as previous one
    },
});
```

It works, but when I add:

```
video: {
        mandatory: {
            maxFrameRate: 15, maxWidth: 320, maxHeight: 240
        }
    }
```

it doesn't work, because hasn't returned true yet(I think).

Could you help me how I can fix it? or even suggest me a new way to decrease the quality in order to use less bandwith.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're using the old constraints style. The new syntax looks like this:

```
video: {
    frameRate: {
        max: 15
    },
    width: {
        max: 320
    },
    height: {
        max: 240
    }
}
```

[source](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#capabilities)

Comment: Thanks dear xdumaine, but where should I return true? before that or after? and one more question, How can I find out that the frame rate decreased correctly? should I use a software that shows the bandwidth or I can do something in javascript? Appreciation

Comment: You don't "return true" - you can either pass `video: true` or the object in my answer in the constraints to `getUserMedia`

Comment: oh you mean just by setting those constraints it will be activated automatically?